# Custom made Facebook like box using their API

Tags: facebook, plugins

I'm pretty frustrated over Facebooks like box (and all their other plugins) so I would like to build my own. The main thing I'm tired of are all the Javascripts and CSS-files being downloaded - with no expire date set! Also Chrome doesn't always seem to like the like box, sometimes it just isn't appearing.

Do you know of anyone who have already done this, i e created an almost exact copy of FB's like box but with custom CSS and without all their included JS and CSS? Is it a tough job building your own like box-like plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use their like button code as it renders as an iframe from their server and cross-domain restrictions won't allow you to manipulate their javascript/css or provide their own.  They also do not offer an API to like a page, as that would get abused by spammers.